# Using multikey indexes for mongo max/min - Find the newest record for a given key

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use a multi-key index to find the newest records by another key.  I can't seem to make it perform.

In pseudo sql I would say

```
create table my_table (user_id int, post_time timestamp, content text);
create index my_index (user_id,post_time) on my_table;
```

I can then then hit the index to find the newest post_time for each user

```
select user_id,max(post_time) from my_table group by user_id
```

All nice and fast even with many millions of records, data will come from the index and we don't hit the table at all.

With Mongo

```
db.my_table.ensureIndex( { user_id:1,post_time:1} )
```

And query

```
db.my_table.aggregate( { $group:{ '_id':'$user_id', 'max':{ $max:'$post_time'} } )
```

But this doesn't hit the index - it seems to do a (slow) table scan.

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "fields" : {
                    "post_time" : 1,
                    "user_id" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "plan" : {
                    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "allPlans" : [
                        {
                            "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "scanAndOrder" : false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$user_id",
                "max" : {
                    "$max" : "$post_time"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What do I need to do here to make this query perform?  Is there a better approach / data structure I should use with mongo?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your `aggregate` query cannot be covered by any index you create.

Only the `$match`, `$sort` and `$geoNear` stages can make use of the indexes when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes),

> **The `$match` and `$sort` pipeline operators can take advantage of an index
>   when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.** New in version 2.4:
>   The `$geoNear` pipeline operator takes advantage of a geospatial index.
>   When using `$geoNear`, the `$geoNear` pipeline operation must appear as
>   the first stage in an aggregation pipeline. **Even when the pipeline
>   uses an index, aggregation still requires access to the actual
>   documents; i.e. indexes cannot fully cover an aggregation pipeline.**

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Any suggestions how to make this kind of query perform using mongo?